# 500 - Internal Server Error while installing magento Index.php/install/wizard/installDb/

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9

After setting database details while installation and submitted. Then it loaded for sometime and got this error **500 - Internal Server Error** while installing in Index.php/install/wizard/installDb/

I check in database there are 250 tables added. Why this error coming? both 1.7 & 1.9 I installed almost 10 times but getting same error. Please Help.

Comment: Most probably  you need to increase execution time of phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 1):

This error might be caused because you have not set the correct permissions for the Magento folders. To solve this go to File Manager and then change the file permission of `index.php` file from 664 to 644. Also change the permissions of `downloader/index.php` file to 644 as well otherwise when you will try to access System > Magento Connect >Magento Connect Manager (after Magento installation) by logging to Magento admin, you will get 500 Internal Server Error.

You can also try this tool, it’s a Magento cleanup utility. It will set the correct permissions for your complete Magento installation:
Download it
Unzip `magento-cleanup.php` to the root directory of your Magento installation
Browse to `http://example.com/magento/magento-cleanup.php`